# authClient isn't working

Tags: firebase

I can't get FireFeed OR my own app working with auth, I followed the documentation for this. I copied in the rules and added the keys, what gives? Example: http://flx.me/firefeed/

Comment: I replied to your tweet already. I guess you didn't see it. You need to set up your "Application Domains" in Forge. In this case, add flx.me (and prob also localhost & 127.0.0.1

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it! :)

Answer (score 1):

One think to check when using the Firebase Simple Login / authClient feature is whether or not you have configured the proper application domain in your account. Any domains that you'll be using to host your application and making authentication requests from should be configured in the 'Application Domains' section of Forge (get here by putting your Firebase URL in a browser). For your application, your domains should include `flx.me`.

Comment: Cool, thanks Rob. I got it everything working! Stupid of me, I switched firebases without adding the domains :)